# How to use Firestore Document Reference in Firebase Cloud Storage Security Rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

```js
allow write: if /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) in 
  firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/businesses/$(businessDocId)).data.team;
```

The `get().data.team` value is an array which contains a Firestore document reference type.

I'm getting a permission error when using this for Cloud Storage, although a similar call in Firestore security rules works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
function isBusinessOwner(businessDocId) {
  let businessTeamArray = firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/businesses/$(businessDocId)).data.team;
  let businessOwner = businessTeamArray[0];
  return businessOwner in businessTeamArray;
}
```

Unfortunately with this solution, I have to manually choose an index in the array, therefore restricting the possibility of having multiple business owners in the array to compare against.

Answer (score 1):

That first line looks off.

What do you expect this to do?

```
/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)
```

If you want to read a field from the document in Firestore, use `firestore.get()` there too, just as you do in the second line:

```
allow write: 
  if firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.fieldToCheck
  in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/businesses/$(businessDocId)).data.team;
```

Comment: The 'team' field contains an array that holds document reference types. I'd like to check if the 'request.auth.uid' is in that 'team' array.

However, I found out it's not as simple to check since you can't compare 'request.auth.uid' with a document reference type.

In Firestore security rules I was able to do inside a function:

let teamArray = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/businesses/$(businessDocId)).data.team;


return /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid) in teamArray;

This line is supposed to imitate a document reference.

Comment: Hey, sorry to tag. Not sure if you got notified of my previous comment. Unfortunately there isn't much documentation or SO answers regarding comparing a document reference type in Cloud Storage Security Rules.